# Java - position of first element satisfying a predicate

Tags: java, list, queue, predicate

I'm programming an ordered queue. On Top there are elements of high priority, sorted from oldest *down to* newest. The same for a section of elements of middle priority in the middle and one for elements of low priority at the bottom.

When I want to sort in a new element, I can often refer to the last element of the list. If the last element has higher or equal priority my new element will be placed after all elements.

Now in the case of the last element beeing of lower priority than my new element, I somehow have to find a way to iterate through the list and find the first element for which the predicate "is of lower priority than the new element" applies. Then my new element shall be at that position.

I'm using compareTo to compare two elements.

I'm a total beginner and I'm having trouble finding a way to solve that problem.

Every help is much appreciated.

Thank you in advance

I tried something like:

```
public Queue<T> queue;

public OrderedQueue() {
    queue = new LinkedList<T>();
}

public void enqueue(T newitem) {
    int sss;
    if (isEmpty()) {
        ((LinkedList<T>) queue).add(newitem);
    }
    else if (newitem instanceof BulkParcel) {
        ((LinkedList<T>) queue).addLast(newitem);
    }
    else if (newitem instanceof StandardParcel || newitem instanceof PriorityParcel) {
            if (newitem.compareTo(((LinkedList<T>) queue).getLast()) == 0) {
                ((LinkedList<T>) queue).addLast(newitem);
            }
            else if (newitem.compareTo(((LinkedList<T>) queue).getLast()) < 0) {
                ((LinkedList<T>) queue).addLast(newitem);
            }
            else
                for (Iterator<T> it = queue.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                sss = newitem.compareTo(it.next());
                ((LinkedList<T>) queue).add((((LinkedList<T>) queue).indexOf(sss==-1)), newitem);
                }
    }
}
```

I was able to accomplish what I wanted.
Here is my new code, for everyone who is still interested.

```
public void enqueue(T newitem) {
    int pos = -1;
    int compVal = 2;
    if (isEmpty()) {
        ((LinkedList<T>) queue).add(newitem);
    }
    else if (newitem.compareTo(((LinkedList<T>) queue).getLast()) == 0 
            || newitem.compareTo(((LinkedList<T>) queue).getLast()) < 0) {
            ((LinkedList<T>) queue).addLast(newitem);
    }
    else {
            for (Iterator<T> it = queue.iterator(); it.hasNext() && compVal != 1;) {
                compVal = newitem.compareTo(it.next());
                pos = pos + 1;
            }
        ((LinkedList<T>) queue).add(pos, newitem);
    }

}
```

I have a self-written method "compareTo" that, for a.compareTo(b);, returns -1, if a is less than b (here that would be the priority), 0 if they are equal, and 1 if a is greater than b.

Thanks for all the help and detailed answers! : )

Comment: [Can we see your code attempts?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried)

Comment: Looks like your reply didn't fit into the comments, add it to the original question?

Comment: Use [edit] option under your question to add new informations. Code can't be properly formatted in comment.

Comment: Also, is this a problem for school? If so the question requires special handling and we'll need the text of the question.

Comment: although this is part of a homework, it's a very small one. I think this is actually very easy to solve, but I just can't figure it out right now...

Comment: I assume (given it's homework) that you can't use Java's PriorityQueue for this?

Comment: I also assume that this would not be allowed.

Comment: Unfortunately the code you posted does not make a lot of sense. You might need to post enough to allow us to understand what you are trying to do. For example how are `queue` and `sss` declared?

Comment: Create an enum (or `String[]`, depending on flexibility needed) with priorities, then make a `LinkedHashMap<T, yourEnum>`, iterate over the map instead of the list, and check the priority as you go, inserting a new item depending on index and priority.

Comment: Sorry, that makes sense... I updated my post.

Comment: @phil_smith unfortunately there's quite a few errors you'll need to fix before we'll be able to help you. I'll post an 'answer' with a few things I suggest you work - I hope that's helpful.

Comment: We're supposed to save all elements in a LinkedList. Can I use a HashMap parallel to that LinkedList? So all I add to my LinkedList is updated in the HashMap?

Comment: That is precisely what @MeetTitan is talking about with the LinkedHashMap, which is a combination HashMap+LinkedList. You can check the docs for it.

Comment: Thank you, @AndrewK. I wish I wasn't so lazy or I'd post a snippet as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at an *insertion sort*. It is almost certainly described in your textbook... though you've got the idea already.

---

`Queue` means something specific; it's for throwing elements in and letting the queue decide where to put them. (e.g. at the end of the list). Since you want to insert at specific places, you want a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html). If you don't want duplicates, you want an [OrderedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html). Declare the field as whichever is most appropriate and avoid casting.

**In every case you should take care to make sure you're not using a library collection that circumvents the learning objectives your instructor has set.**

Depending on what the instructor wants from you, you may be able to use one of these and finish in just a few lines of code. Or they might all be forbidden and you have to hack it yourself. Find out!

---

I have suggestions for making it easier for you to understand your own code. For example, take this line:

```
if (newitem.compareTo(((LinkedList<T>) queue).getLast()) == 0) {
```

is the same as

```
if (lastItemIsEqualTo(newItem)) {
```

if you add the following *helper method*:

```
private boolean lastItemIsEqualTo(T newItem) {
     return newItem.compareTo(((LinkedList<T>) queue).getLast()) == 0;
}
```

working this forward, you might end up with:

```
        if (lastItemIsEqualTo(newItem)) {
            stuff...
        }
        else if (lastItemIsLessThan(newItem) {
            stuff...
        }
        else for (Iterator<T> it = queue.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            otherStuff...
        }
```

which is equivalent to:

```
        if (lastItemIsLessThanOrEqualTo(newItem)) {
            stuff...
        }
        else for (Iterator<T> it = queue.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            otherStuff...
        }
```

but you could also say what you're really wanting to accomplish with that if statement:

```
        if (entireListComesBefore(newItem)) {
            stuff...
        }
        else for (Iterator<T> it = queue.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            otherStuff...
        }
```

---

`StandardParcel` vs `BulkParcel`. Are two classes necessary? For example, if `BulkParcel` is the same as a `StandardParcel` only with a single item, you could just use `Parcel`, but have something like follows:

```
public boolean isABulkParcel() {
    return parcel.size() > 1;
}
```

and have algorithms that are generalized for both. Then you wouldn't need `instanceof`. There are very few uses for `instanceof` that there are not better solutions for.

---

```
sss = newitem.compareTo(it.next());
queue.add(queue.indexOf(sss==-1), newitem);
```

`sss` makes no sense. You have a logical error here, and you'd see it quickly if your variable name made more sense. Look:

```
boolean newItemGoesBeforeNextItem = newitem.compareTo(it.next()) == -1;
queue.add(queue.indexOf(newItemGoesBeforeNextItem), newitem);
```

Now do you see the problem in the last line? That's a `boolean`, not numeric index. It automatically gets converted into an object `Boolean` (note the upper case). So it tries to search through the list for that Boolean object and never finds it. It's doing this, basically:

```
queue.indexOf(new Boolean(sss == 1))
```

This is a really big deal. If you don't understand it, take the time to look at it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few errors in your code that I suggest you fix before you tackle this problem:

1. why are you constantly casting `queue` to `LinkedList`? Many of the methods you call are implemented for `Queue` in any case. But if you specifically need `List` methods then it should be declared as a `List`.
2. `queue` should be `private`.
3. `instanceof` is usually a sign that you have something wrong with your class structure. In your case you should almost certainly declare your class and queue with an abstract class or interface called `Parcel` of which the various parcels are implementations or extensions.
4. Your comparator should either be the natural ordering of `Parcel` (i.e. the instances themselves implement `compareTo`) or you should implement your own comparator to encapsulate your definition of priority. It should not be embedded in your `enqueue` method. For example, what happens if the priority of a parcel changes? Ideally you want to be able to resort using a defined comparator.
5. There are naturally sorted collection classes in Java. The simplest solution, once you've implemented the comparator, is to use one of these with the constructor that allows you to designate your own comparator.

Hope that helps.